# why am I seeing a black screen when I try this code in cuda?

Tags: cuda, nsight

I'm using Win8 and Nsight in "visual studio 2010" and I installed "310.90-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-32bit-international-whql" for my Graphic card(9300m Gs).but when I try the code below,I see a black screen!and an error :"Display driver stoped responding and has recoverd"!
I know that the problem is with "cudaMemcpy",but I don't why!?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define N 8
__global__ void kernel(int *a)
{
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int step = x;
while(step<N){
    a[step] =  threadIdx.x;
    step += x;
}
}

int main()
{
int a[N],i=N,j=0;
for(;j<N;j++)
    a[j]=i--;

int *dev_a;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int) );
cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<2,2>>>(dev_a);

cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(a, dev_a,N-1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    //goto Error;
}

for(j=0;j<N;j++)printf("\n%d",a[j]);

int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA limit seems to be reached, but what limit is that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913206/cuda-limit-seems-to-be-reached-but-what-limit-is-that)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the kernel, the thread with `threadIdx.x` = 0 and `blockIdx.x` = 0 i.e. the first thread of the first block will run indefinitely, causing the kernel to crash.

When `threadIdx.x` = 0 and `blockIdx.x` = 0 the kernel code will become:

```
int x = 0;
int step = 0;
while(step<N)
{
    a[step] =  0;
    step += 0; //This will create infinite loop
}
```

Also (May be its a typo), there is a logical error in the following line of your code:

```
cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(a, dev_a,N-1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Considering the operator precedence in C, the expression `N-1 * sizeof(int)` will evaluate to `N-4` (if `sizeof(int)` is 4).