# How threads/blocks are mapped on GPU while calling cublasSgemm/clAmdBlasSgemm routines?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu, blas, cublas

I am interested in knowing how `cublasSgemm`/`clAmdBlasSgemm` routines are mapped on GPU while calculating matrix multiplication (C = A * B).

Assume the dimensions of input Matrix ::A_rows =  6144;
 A_cols = 12288; B_rows = 12288; B_cols = 15360;

and dimensions of resultant matrix :: C_rows =  6144; C_cols = 15360;

Assume i have initialized the input matrices on host and i copied the matrix data into device memory. After that i am calling following `cuBlas` or `clAmdBlas` routines to do matrix multiplication on GPU.

```
void cublasSgemm (char transa, char transb, int m, int n, int k, float alpha, const float *A, int lda, const float *B, int ldb, float beta, float *C, int ldc);
```

where m = A_rows; and 
      n = B_cols;

So my doubts are:
1. ) How these routines are implemented on GPU ?
2. ) Does m and n values mapped on one compute unit (SM)? If No, then what can be maximum value for m and n ?
3. ) Do we have control of threads/Blocks ?

Comment: Are you really wanting to know about CUBLAS or whatever the OpenCL library you are asking about? Do you imagine there is a common answer which applies to both?

Comment: @talonmies Yes, I want to know how these routines are defined ?

Comment: That is two completely different questions. Pick one of them.

Comment: @talonmies I want to know only how threads/blocks are controlled while calling these routines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the host side CUBLAS API (note that I have no idea why you would assume that clAmdBlasSgemm would be the same), the short answer to your questions are as follows:

1. Modern CUBLAS is closed source. There are code bases like [Magma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/index.html) which you could look at to at least get a feel for how CUBLAS *might* be implemented. You can also run CUBLAS code in one of the NVIDIA supplied profilers to see what it does on the GPU. But the point is that you don't need to know how it works. There is an  API and some very thorough documentation. That is all you need to know.
2. You example problem requires roughly 1.2Gb of memory. If you have a GPU with that much memory, and either enough computational capacity to avoid the [display driver watchdog timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6913206/681865), or a compute dedicated GPU, it will work. Memory and the display driver time limitations (where applicable) are the only limitations.
3. No.

Note that there is also a CUBLAS device API for K20 Kepler devices, and the answers I provided above do not apply to that library.

Comment: As per your second point, i understood that the value of m and n in cublasSgemm() routines will be mapped on all the SMs (not only on one SM). Is it so ?

Comment: @Gopal: That is an implementation detail which is not exposed. You can check what goes on by profiling a running call, if you really wanted to but you don't have to know any of this to use CUBLAS.

Answer (score 0):

Before going any further you must read the papers of Volkov and Demmel, have a look here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/ see his article regarding SGEMM. The answers are there since 2008.